# Grid view for Events on travel website

Tags: grid

I can't decide which is the best option for this type of grid view.

The problem is that I need to have all the information listed below:

- Picture
- Price
- Icon
- Date (can be shown as a range or as a fixed date) +  tag (Today, in 5 days, underway, yesterday, etc.. )
- Name of the event
- City

Date is very improtant in this search, and when I put everything all together it looks messed up.

I would be very grateful for an opinion :)!

Here you can the the grid view, and how it looks in list view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You clearly have a problem of information presentation. There are 3 differents layouts in your grid and the style is not consistent (why so many greens? why "in 56 days" and "Today" have a different aspect?). You may want to start here.

Comment: As it stands this is a "please review my site" type question - which isn't allowed.  Please ask a specific UX question about your problem so that the answers are useful to other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

Show only important / key information for each item.

Have a **View More Details** Icon for each item and on mouse click or mouse over, show more details in a small dialog.

[image]

Comment: tnanks a lot, a aprecciate it!

Answer (score 0):

From those 3 options I prefer the left one because it aligns to the left better than the others.

I would consider adding a light gray background behind the text and wrap it all (the picture and the text) with a thin frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can show more details on hover like this -

[image]

(taken from an ecommerce site)

Answer (score 0):

Second is better solution for me, but in each case the eye goes to the price first, the date is the second step. To solve the alignment problem try to center the town.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow can you elaborate?